# Trying to view the contents of a text file in powershell. Getting "more.com" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm using this [tutorial](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex12.html). The exercises shows the basic use of `less` and `more`.

Except from link

```
> more ex12.txt
[displays file here]
>
```

When i try to use the 'more' command, i get the error:

> the term 'more.com' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   functoin, script file, or operable program.Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

I'm not sure what is going on and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the **relevant code** here. Questions posted here should be self-contained; links should only be used as additional references. Your question is meaningless for future readers if the external site is unavailable (eg., moved, renamed, off-line). It also has no content that is searchable for those future readers either. If you want help, include the information here so we don't have to go elsewhere to figure out what you're asking. The [help] has more information about how to ask questions here.

Comment: Any reason why you are testing Command line utilities and tagged PowerShell? Normally I would say your Path environment variable might be missing something but it's odd that it actually says `more.com` is missing.

Comment: well, im just following the tutorial. he said to use powershell for this. and how would i go about checking if the environment variable is missing? just in case?

Comment: `More.com` should be located in "C:\Windows\System32". In PowerShell you can check path with `$env:Path`

Comment: i just checked and there is no 'more' folder in that path

Comment: Starting to feel that there is a bigger learning curve ahead for you. The com file `more.com` is located in "C:\Windows\System32". Do you have "C:\Windows\System32" in your Path variable?

Comment: right now, my path variable is set to:
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

. There is no "more" folder in my system32 folder

Comment: There is no "more" folder at all. `more.com` is a command-line pager (an executable) shipped with Windows and is (or should be) located in `C:\Windows\system32`, as Matt already told you. What is the output of `dir C:\windows\system32\more.com`?

Answer (score 2):

There must be something wrong with your PC's configuration because more.com should work just fine in PowerShell e.g.:

```
PS C:\> more.com .\foo.ini
foo=this is foo section
bar=this is the bar section
```

In fact, PowerShell *does* use more.com.  Take a look at the definition of the `more` function (which the `help` function pipes into). In the `more` function you will see these two lines:

```
Get-Content $file | more.com
...
$input | more.com
```

So when you execute "more" you are executing a PowerShell function that invokes more.com.  Have you tried `more.com ex12.txt`?

Also, more.com comes in 32-bit and 64-bit flavors:

```
PS C:\> Get-PEHeader c:\windows\system32\more.com


Type                    : PE64
LinkerVersion           : 11.0
```

`Get-PEHeader` is from [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 0):

powershell doesn't use more.com, it's a 16 bit binary which I believe is no longer included in x64 based windows. on 32bit yes we may find one. However in powershell you can pipe the output to out-file -paging cmdlet and it should do the job

```
get-content .\pylongcode.py | out-host -Paging
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set your path variable.

to check the path variable you can type **PS>>** *echo $env:path*
If you do not see a very long string of C:\Windows.... separated by ";" that is a problem I would recommend you resolve with MS support if you are not able to get help from here or your computer manufacturer.

A simple way to set your path is

**PS>>** ${NewFileName.txt} = $env:path
**PS>>** NewFileName.txt
*File should open in notepad add new paths*

**[notepad]** C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;

**Save**

**PS>>** $env:path = ${NewFileName.txt}
**PS>>** $env:path

Double Check that the path now has the contents of that file.  You can then delete the file as it is only used to aid in editing the path variable.  There are other ways to do this I prefer this way because I prefer using a text editor for editing over a terminal.  Having those two entries will get less and more working.

Comment: Quite possibly. But what should they set it to? How do they set it? Assume that if setting the path variable is the answer, readers may not know how to do that. Can you edit your answer to offer further guidance?